# Passing JSON parse value to a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$(function() {

        var global_datalength = 0;
        leavereminder();
        alert(global_datalength);

    });


function leavereminder() {
        $.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>home/leavereminder",
            {},
            function(data) {
                if(data.length != 0) {
                    for(x=0; x<data.length; x++) {
                        var lblm = document.createElement('div');        
                        lblm.innerHTML = '<label>'+data[x]+'</label>';  
                        lblm.className = 'alert alert-info';                  
                        document.getElementById('notifbody').appendChild(lblm);           
                    }
                }
                var datalength = data.length;
        });
        global_datalength = datalength;
    }
```

I have a global variable of global_datalength and i want to replace it with my return json 
but when i alert my code it always 0. it didnt pass my global_datalength = datalength. because when outside of json function my data.length is unknown

Comment: `global_datalength` is local in the first function. And even if it wasn't - the `leavereminder` function is asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `var` keyword on `global_datalength` to make it global.

You can also use `window.global_datalength`.

Another way is to declare the variable outside the jQuery ready function.

---

Your JSON call is async. That means the alert will be called before the JSON has returned from the server.

What you can do is:

```
function leavereminder() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>home/leavereminder",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.length != 0) {
                for(x=0; x<data.length; x++) {
                    var lblm = document.createElement('div');        
                    lblm.innerHTML = '<label>'+data[x]+'</label>';  
                    lblm.className = 'alert alert-info';                  
                    document.getElementById('notifbody').appendChild(lblm);           
                }
            }
            global_datalength = datalength;
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: I remove my global_datalength = 0, but my error is  datalength is not defined

Comment: Your var datalength is out of scope when used outside of your $.getJSON.

Comment: @VictorSoto yes thats my problem i want to get my values inside my json and pass it outside

Answer (score 0):

Need to keep `global_datalength` outside the jQuery function.

Also since `leavereminder` is asynchronous, you might want to keep `global_datalength = datalength;` inside the `function(data)`

```
var global_datalength = 0;

 $(function () {
     leavereminder();
 });

 function leavereminder() {
     $.getJSON("<?=base_url()?>home/leavereminder", {},

     function (data) {
         if (data.length != 0) {
             for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                 var lblm = document.createElement('div');
                 lblm.innerHTML = '<label>' + data[x] + '</label>';
                 lblm.className = 'alert alert-info';
                 document.getElementById('notifbody').appendChild(lblm);
             }
         }
         global_datalength = data.length;
         alert(global_datalength);
     });

 }
```

Comment: It always alert 0 even i did global_datalength = 5;

Comment: alert(data) in the JSON response function and check if it returns something.